# How to assign type of ObjectIdentifier during its definition in sapui5?

Tags: sapui5

I know how its possible to define UI controls as follows:

```
<Text text="{ path: 'some-path',
              type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date',
              formatOptions: {source: {pattern: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}, style: 'long'}
             }"/>
```

What's the syntax like if I wish to define an ObjectIdentifier like that?

```
<ObjectIdentifier text="{some-path}" title="{some-path}"/>
```

How do I specify 'type' for **title** and **text**?
Kindly help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like in your first example:

```
<ObjectIdentifier 
    text="{
        path: 'some-path',
        type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date',
        formatOptions: {source: {pattern: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}, style: 'long'}
    }"
    title="{
        path: 'some-path',
        type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date',
        formatOptions: {source: {pattern: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}, style: 'long'}
    }"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely the same.

```xml
<ObjectIdentifier text="{ path: 'some-path',
                          type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date',
                          formatOptions: {source: {pattern: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}, style: 'long'}
                        }"
                  title="{ path: 'some-other-path',
                           type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date',
                           formatOptions: {source: {pattern: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}, style: 'long'}
                         }" />
```

There are some predefined Types available in the namespace [sap.ui.model.type](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.type-1.html).

The use in XMLViews is always

```json
{ path: 'some-path',
  mode: 'sap.ui.model.BindingMode.OneWay' //See documentation of BindingMode for possible values
  type: 'full.class.name or .propertyInController'
  formatOptions: { .. } //object as described in the constructor documentation of the type
  constraints: { .. } //object as described in the constructor documentation of the type
  parameters: { .. } //object with additional binding parameters (most depending on the model type)
  formatter: 'full.function.name or .functionInController'
}
```

You can use either `formatter` or `type`. If you use `type`, you can use `formatOptions` and `constraints`. `mode` and `parameters` can always be used.

If you just want to supply `path` you can use the short form: `text="{some-path}"`

For aggregation bindings (in contrast to property bindings) there different options: there is no `type` or `formatter` but instead you can provide `sorter` and `filter`.